# Doctrine EntityManagerDecorator

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've created custom decorator for EntityManager and now when I'm doing 
`doctrine->getManager()`, then I can get my custom manager class, but inside repository class I still have native EntityManager how can I fix this. Or maybe there is another way to set something inside repository classes from container?

Decorator calls getRepository on $wrapped(EntityManager) and then $wrapped pass $this inside RepositoryFactory $this == $wrapped == EntityManager

My solution is:

```
    public function getRepository($className)
    {
        $repository = parent::getRepository($className);
        if ($repository instanceof MyAbstractRepository) {
            $repository->setDependency();
        }
        return $repository;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches:

1. Copy the static EntityManager::createRepository code to your entity manager class and adjust it accordingly.  This is fragile since any change to the EntityManager code might break your code.  You have to keep track of doctrine updates.  However, it can be made to work.
2. A second approach is to define your repositories as services.  You could then inject your entity manager in the repository.  Bit of a hack but it avoids cloning the createRepository code.
3. The third approach is the recommended approach.  Don't decorate the entity manager.  Think carefully about what you are trying to do.  In most cases, Doctrine events or a custom base repository class can handle your needs.  And it saves you from fooling around with the internals.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to override the entity manager service classes or parameters via a [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html).